OS appending IP header even with raw sockets and IPPROTO_RAW
I have two programs, a sender and a receiver. The sender sends an ICMP echo request packet to the receiver using raw sockets. After reading the man-7 page on raw sockets and this blog, my understanding is, if I use IPPROTO_RAW, I would be enabling the IP_HDRINCL option, which would tell the OS not to add any IP header as the sender would be supplying it.
However, I still see an unexpected IP header being added when I capture packets using tcpdump.
➜ ~ tcpdump -nt -i lo0 not tcp -X
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on lo0, link-type NULL (BSD loopback), snapshot length 524288 bytes

IP 127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1:  ip-proto-255 28
    0x0000:  4500 0030 f9a2 0000 40ff 0000 7f00 0001  E..0....@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 4500 0000 0000 0000 4001 0000  ....E.......@...
    0x0020:  0000 0000 7f00 0001 0800 f7ff 0000 0000  ................

For clarity,
// the unexpected IP header
45 00 00 30 a8 d4 00 00 40 ff 00 00 7f 00 00 01 7f 00 00 01 

// my IP header
45 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 7f 00 00 01 

// my ICMP bytes
08 00 f7 ff 00 00 00 00

Things to note

There's one observation here, the IP header added by the OS has a value 255 for the protocol field which is Reserved. I don't know why it's that and if there's something to infer here.
As per the man-7 page, when IP_HDRINCL is enabled, the OS will fill in the identification, source address, checksum, and total length fields. Hence, I've set them to zero in my IP header.

This is my sender program
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "syscall"
)

func main() {
    fd, _ := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.IPPROTO_RAW)
    addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1},
    }

    // identification, src address, checksum, and total length will be set by the kernel since IP_HDRINCL is enabled.
    ipHeader := []byte{
        0x45,       // VersionIHL
        0x00,       // ToS
        0x00, 0x00, // total length
        0x00, 0x00, // identification
        0x00, 0x00, // flags and fragment offset
        0x40,       // ttl
        0x01,       // protocol is ICMP
        0x00, 0x00, // checksum

        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // src address
        0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, // dest address
    }
    p := append(ipHeader, 0x08, 0x00, 0xf7, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00)

    err := syscall.Sendto(fd, p, 0, &addr)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("send to error: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("sent %d bytes\n", len(p))
}

I'm curious to know why the OS is appending the IP header. Is there any gap in my understanding of raw sockets?
Thanks!

I'm coming from this blog post of yours. For sake of completeness, would you mind adding an answer to this question summarizing what worked for you? This would be useful to others who have the same problem in the future.

@MichaelM. Yes, absolutely. I will do that.

It's lo on my machine (Ubuntu 6.8.0-35-generic), and I get
# tcpdump -nt -i lo not tcp -X -vv
tcpdump: listening on lo, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 63468, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 28)
    127.0.0.1 > 127.0.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 0, seq 0, length 8
    0x0000:  4500 001c f7ec 0000 4001 84f2 7f00 0001  E.......@.......
    0x0010:  7f00 0001 0800 f7ff 0000 0000            ............

What I wonder is why you'll get link type NULL while I'm getting ETHERNET. We probably need to know more about the machine you are executing your code on.
Note that when you are on a non-Linux machine, the Linux man pages obviously don't apply. For example macOS ip(4) says:

If proto is 0, the default protocol IPPROTO_RAW is used for outgoing
packets, and only incoming packets destined for that protocol are
received. If proto is non-zero, that protocol number will be used on
outgoing packets and to filter incoming packets.
Outgoing packets automatically have an IP header prepended to them
(based on the destination address and the protocol number the socket
is created with), unless the IP_HDRINCL option has been set. Incoming
packets are received with IP header and options intact.

similarly on FreeBSD you have ip (4):

If  proto  is  0, the default protocol IPPROTO_RAW is used for outgoing
packets,  and only incoming packets destined for that protocol  are  received.
If  proto  is non-zero, that protocol number will be used on
outgoing  packets and to filter incoming packets.
Outgoing  packets automatically have an  IP  header  prepended  to  them
(based on the destination address and the protocol number the socket is
created   with),  unless  the IP_HDRINCL option has been set.  Unlike in
previous  BSD releases, incoming packets are received with IP header and
options intact, leaving all fields in network byte order.

So IPPROTO_RAW implying IP_HDRINCL is not true on every platform, what you are seeing would be fine on a macOS machine - but you are using the wrong documentation for that.

Thanks for this answer, you were correct to infer that I was referring to the wrong docs. Your answer propelled me to explore raw sockets in depth and I've learned a lot since then.

As rightly inferred by Eik in their answer above, I was referencing the wrong documentation (Linux) for the system I was programming on, which was macOS.
MacOS and Linux, being different operating systems, handle raw sockets differently. FreeBSD raw sockets exhibit some peculiarities that are mentioned here. Once I made the system-specific adjustments in the code, I was able to get it working. No changes were needed for the receiver program; only the sender program required modifications.
Modifications

As per the linux manual, passing IPPROTO_RAW for the protocol argument in the syscall is sufficient to enable IP_HDRINCL option on the socket. However, on macOS, that alone didn't do it. The option has to be enabled using SetsockoptInt() function.

For macOS, Total Length and Offset are supposed to be in host-byte order while writing to a raw socket. Since in my case, offset was zero, I only had to handle the Total Length field.

In Linux, certain fields get auto-filled if IP_HDRINCL is enabled.

Checksum and Total Length fields are always filled in.
Source address and Identification fields are filled in when they are zero.

Hence, I calculate these values only when the program is running on
macOS. For Linux, I leave them as zero, allowing the kernel to handle
the calculations.


Here's the updated code.
func main() {
    fd, _ := syscall.Socket(syscall.AF_INET, syscall.SOCK_RAW, syscall.IPPROTO_RAW)
    addr := syscall.SockaddrInet4{
        Addr: [4]byte{127, 0, 0, 1},
    }

    ipHeader := []byte{
        0x45,       // versionIHL
        0x00,       // tos
        0x00, 0x00, // len
        0x00, 0x00, // id
        0x00, 0x00, // ffo
        0x40,       // ttl
        0x01,       // protocol
        0x00, 0x00, // checksum

        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // src
        0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, // dest
    }
    data := []byte{0x08, 0x00, 0xf7, 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00}

    if runtime.GOOS == "darwin" {
        // setting IP_HDRINCL socket option explicitly
        _ = syscall.SetsockoptInt(fd, syscall.IPPROTO_IP, syscall.IP_HDRINCL, 1)

        // Populating total length in host byte order
        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint16(ipHeader[2:4], 28)
        
        // Filling the fields that are auto filled in linux systems but not on mac.
        copy(ipHeader[12:16], []byte{127, 0, 0, 1})
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(ipHeader[4:6], 11)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(ipHeader[10:12], calculateChecksum(ipHeader))
    }

    p := append(ipHeader, data...)

    fmt.Printf("Transmitting bytes:\n% x\n", p)

    _ := syscall.Sendto(fd, p, 0, &addr)

    fmt.Printf("Sent %d bytes\n", len(p))
}

With these changes, the sender program was able to send out the proper echo-request and the receiver program running on the other terminal was able to receive the echo-reply as well.

I've tested this code on macOS Sonoma 14.6 (my personal computer) and a 22.04 Ubuntu VM and it works fine on both systems. I wrote about my learnings in detail in this blog post.

As mentioned in private conversation: Are you aware of golang.org/x/net/icmp? A lot of platform dependent stuff is handled there.

Hey, I just got a chance to write an elaborate response to your email. For the readers here, back then, it didn't even cross my mind to reference this package as I got tunnel-visioned for being stuck on this for so long. I was lacking clarity of mind.
